# How to set filter on div html attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs and one button. Divs have `zozo [j]` attribute .

When I click on the button, I want their id to be set, but not all divs, just those that have `j > k`. In fact I want to use a filter.

```
<div zozo="sim [0]"></div>
<div zozo="sim [1]"></div>
<div zozo="sim [2]"></div>
   .
   . // and some div else 
   . 
var k = 1;
```

I know the below code is wrong, but I want something like this:

```
$("div [zozo='sim ["+ > = k + "]' ]").attr('id' , k+1);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Posting invalid syntax does not help.

Comment: Why it is not clear. I want to select divs that have  sim [j] . But j   >= 1.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so what you'll have to do here is iterate over each element and then do your calculations on the value of each one individually. You're talking about a selector based on some arithmetic calculation - I don't believe that exists.

Here is how I would do it:

```
var k = 1;
$( "div[zozo^='sim']" ).each( function(){
  var value = $( this ).attr( "zozo" ).match(/(\d+)/)[1]; // remove all except the  number
  value = parseInt( value ); // convert it into an actual number
  if ( value >= k ){
    // if a condition is met - we update the attribute of the current element
    $( this ).attr( "id", (value + k ) );
  }
});
```

I'm using jquery's ["attribute starts with" selector here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) that matches all elements that have a `zozo` class value that starts with the string "sim".

---

Note that in your example you're wanting setting the `id` attribute to `k+1`. This will always remain the same number and so you'll be setting multiple elements with the same `id`. You don't want to be doing that. In my example I've made sure that each `id` attribute is unique.

Check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tZ7ct/6/), you'll see that all but the first red box have their `id` set.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to do:

```
$("div[zozo^=sim]" ).attr('id' , function(i){ //Use attribute startswith seletor
    //return i+1; //return index + 1 as  the id
     return +$(this).attr('zozo').match(/(\d+)/).pop() + 1;
});
```

Or just set a common class name to all those elements and use class selector

```
$("div.myClass" ).attr('id' , function(i){ //Use attribute startswith seletor
   return i+1; //return index + 1 as  the id
});
```

Also remember that `zozo` is not a valid attribute, prefix it with `data-*` would be more appropriate.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F3g4E/)**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? WARNING, UGLY CODE

```
$('#parentdiv > div').each(function () {
    var $that = $(this);
    var zozo = parseInt($that.attr('zozo').replace('sin[', '').replace(']', ''));
    if (zozo >= k)
        $that.id = k + 1;
});
```

Comment: `$.each()` on a ID selector?

Comment: @MackieeE: Good catch. Removed now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value of data-zozo is always in the same format, and assuming I've understood your question correctly, this should work. You'd want to use a more specific selector, of course.

```
$('div').click(function () {
    var myK = $(this).attr('data-zozo');
    myK = myK.charAt(5);
    myK = parseInt(myK);

    if (myK >= 1) {
        $(this).attr('id',myK + 1);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5g7yU/